# How to Exclude Certain times from one column in r?

Tags: r, mean

I want to find the mean of each column in the dataset airquality in RStudio. I want to only include values where the month is July (7) and then find the mean. I thought of doing filter so I could filter through the column and assign it to a variable and then find the mean of each column.
Is there a way to do this in a single line command?

Here's my code so far:

```
apply(airquality[,1:6],2,mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you,`lapply(subset(airquality, Month == 7), mean, na.rm = T) %>% unlist()`